# Beginners Vb: Variable Scope misunderstanding

Tags: vb.net, scope

OK so i just started to learn vb and did some experimenting until i came across this thing which i cant understand

So i have a console application with two modules

**Module1.vb** (program starts form this)

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        add.addone()
        add.addone()
        add.addone()
        Console.Read()
    End Sub

End Module
```

**add.vb**

```
Public Module add
    Private counter As Integer

    Public Sub addone()
        counter += 1
        Console.Write(counter)
    End Sub
End Module
```

I expect it to print on the console a pattern of:

1
1
1

Why does it print out

1
2
3

Im asking this because, what i understand is, after add.addone() is called. The variable (counter) should no longer exist! So when add.addone() is called for the **second** time it should be blank and thus, printing out 1 again.

I hope you can help me. What am i doing wrong and why is this happening?

thanks,
Vidhu

Comment: You are somehow hoping that VB creates *objects* with this syntax.  Instances of a class that store their own *counter*.  That requires the "Class" keyword, the polar opposite of "Module".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> after add.addone() is called. The variable (counter) should no longer exist!

Why would that be? `counter` is declared *outside* of `addone`, in the surrounding module `add`. So of course it remains in existence even after the method exits.

(Incidentally, you should follow the .NET PascalCase naming convention for modules and methods …)

Comment: i thought that a module was like a class but insteads it is not put in a variable to hold values. and its like a place where you can group methods and functions which can then be called form anywhere.

I didnt know that it keeps it values in its global variables, even after it is done being called.

Thanks though!

Comment: @Vidhu Close enough. But variables declared inside a module are still *of the module*, i.e. they don’t come into scope and go out of scope as functions are called, they stay alive. Apart from that, modules are obsolete for the most part (not because they are bad, but because they don’t interoperate well with other .NET languages) – the exception being for extension methods where modules are *needed*.

Comment: suppose i make it a class. is there a way i  can still call the methods without initiating the class?

Comment: @Vidhu You can do that, simply make the methods (and the class-scope variables that it uses) `Shared`.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the variable counter is declared inside a Module not inside a Class.
When a program changes a public variable in a module, any other part of the program gets the same value. You can't create instances of a Module like you do with Class where every instance has its own copy of the internal variables.

See [Module vs Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/7825002w%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)